# Replace '\n' with '' in python dictionary

Tags: python, json

I'm reading from dataset with json objects, in dataset some of values has abcd\nabdc format. I used following code:

```
for line in open("c:\\dataset","r+").readlines():
       d= json.loads(line)
       str1 = d['strkey1']
       str1.replace('\n' , '')
```

but it fails to replace.

Comment: you must store the replaced object somewhere!

Comment: `dict` is a builtin, don't use it as a name, I've changed it to `d` for you

Answer (score 4):

```
d['strkey1'] = d['strkey1'].replace('\n', '')
```

Strings are immutable, so string methods return new strings, **not** modifying the original.

Also:

```
for line in open("c:\\dataset","r+"):
```

Will suffice, you don't need to `.readlines()` the whole file into memory before going through each line. But that still isn't enough, you need to remember to close your files, a `with` statement will handle that for you:

```
with open("c:\\dataset","r+") as f:
    for line in f:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: @Mahdi strings are immutable(can't be changed or manipulated) so you need to assign the result back to `str1`

Comment: @jamylak That's not enough. a `dict['strkey1'] = ...` is required as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your code to:

```
for line in open("c:\\dataset","r+").readlines():
       dict = json.loads(line)
       dict['strkey1'] = dict['strkey1'].replace('\n','')
```

This works and your's doesn't as strings are immutable (they can't be changed), so string methods return a new string, (which here you need to store)